# Blender Multitextures Normal maps

Tags: texturing, materials, game-engine, normals

as says the title: is it possible to use normal mapping in Multitexture mode, if yes how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible.

Multitexture is a fixed-function pipeline which can do multiple layers of diffuse textures, but lighting information is calculated per-vertex. This means that maps that contain information that should influence lighting have no effect (eg specular hardness, specular intensity, normal, height).
In GLSL mode, lighting is calculated per-pixel, and so these maps can be used.

**In short: In multitexture, the only maps supported are emit, diffuse (with some trickery) and transparency.**

I highly recommend GLSL. Most hardware made in the last decade or so supports it. If you are concerned about the performance of GLSL, I will point out that it depends mainly on the complexity of your shaders. If you simply use diffuse, emit and transparency maps, the performance is virtually the same as multitexture. GLSL offers more functionality, allowing more effects, and it is these *extra* effects that cause performance loss.

That said, I used multitexture for many years because my hardware didn't support it. You can do some great looking stuff in multitexture mode if you are clever.

EDIT:
Apparently if you have old enough hardware, the performance difference between GLSL and multitexture is noticeable, even on simple scenes.

Comment: Great answer yet you say: "the performance is virtually the same as multitexture." It's not true. my computer is not handling GLSL as fast (I should say it lags more) as Multitexturing, even with a simple solid color. Thanks for claryfing.

Comment: Oh! I am surprised! What hardware is this on, and how many lights do you have?

Comment: One Sun in the scene...I'm using an Asus Eeepc from 2008. CPU Intel Celeron M 900Mhz,
1gb ram, 
OpenGl Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915GMx86/MMX/SSE2
:)

Comment: Hmm, 8 year old netbook. Yeah, I can see why performance is suffering. I'd say stick with multitexture unless you get better hardware.